# JQuery Tooltip content override not working for me

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, tooltip

Hi I have the following code at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uda2684/Lxnudsav/42/) but the tooltip isn't being replaced by the text specified in JQuery's tooltip content option.
What am I doing wrong, misunderstanding or missing completely.
Thanks.

Html

```
<a id="linkB" href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="To Be replaced">Link with replaced content</a>
```

JS

```
$('#linkB').tooltip({content:'LinkB Tooptip replaced via text in the content option of tooltip'});
```

Comment: Your tooltip in `jsfiddle` isn't from jquery-ui, it's from bootstrap. Why do i emphasis this? because, jquery tooltip and bootstrap tooltip is different in options.

Comment: I removed jquery tag and add `bootstrap-4` which isn't what i wanted, but tag `bootstrap-3` not exists.

Answer (score 0):

I first changed the title and then called tooltip which worked for me.
Let me know if you face the problem in this solution.

```
$('#table_row1').attr('title', "Replaced via text in the content option of tooltip").tooltip();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've confused that you are using jquery-ui tooltip.
*(You should remove `jqueryui`tag and add `bootstrap`, for other visitors.)*

But after minutes, i realized you used bootstrap tooltip.

Anyway, solution is to use `title` option instead of `content` and also remove `title` attribute in html tag.

I append my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8opunht9/)

Comment: Thanks @coding monster. How do you and jsfiddle know it is a bootstrap tooltip? Where/how is the bootstrap/jquery/other module hierarchy determined?

Comment: @kc2684 you can see _Resources_ panel on the left of the screen at jsfiddle. There, you added bootstrap js&css, and also the style of tooltip and attribute like `data-*` says that you used bootstrap tooltip, not jquery-ui tooltip. :-0

Comment: Thanks :) just found the resources panel myself. Sorry for the inconvenience.